# Convert given string to minutes when text box loses focus

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, webforms

I'm developing a form in which there is a field called Available From,(time should be entered in minutes for that text bod) the user if enters 2h(hours) in the text box, then as soon as it loses focus , the 2h should get converted into mins, same for when entered in days, eg: 2d should get converted into 2880 mins, should appear on the text box. If entered in mins, then should remain in mins. I'm new to java script and jQuery. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is the question, please write this for me?

Comment: SO isn't a place to ask people to do your work. Attempt it yourself and then ask questions if you cannot do it (showing what you have attempted).

Comment: Look up 'blur' events first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your are just testing. It is not very useful for real-world scenario, because there are too many possibilities.

First of all, use [jQuery blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/). Then convert the input value to appropriate minutes.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").blur(function () {
        var input = $(this).val();
        // Apply your logic here
        if (input.match(/h$/)) {
            $(this).val(input.slice(0, -1) * 60);
        }
        else if (input.match(/d$/)) {
            $(this).val(input.slice(0, -1) * 60 * 24);
        }
        console.log(input);
    })
</script>
```